# c-bind from a list of data tables without recycling and with using list names as part of column names

Tags: r, merge, apply, cbind

This is a follow-up question to a very [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77142219/c-r-bind-from-a-list-of-data-tables-w-o-recycling-and-w-using-list-names-as-pa) where I already received great help here but I'm failing to modify the solution to the new requirements.

I have a list of data frames with different row count each. I would like to use the name of each data frame to rename all (not just the 1st) columns in each data frame. Then I would like to add a column with a row number into each of the data frames in order to use merge to cbind all of them.

Again my small example to create a short list of data frames:

```
# Create dummy list of data frames
df1 <- data.frame(border=c(1,2,3), value=c(4,5,6))
df2 <- data.frame(border=as.factor(c("A","B")), value=c(3,5.7))
df_lst <- list(df1, df2)
names(df_lst) <- c("df1","df2")
```

This time the desired output should look like so:

```
  df1 border df1 value df2 border df2 value
1          1         4          A       3.0
2          2         5          B       5.7
3          3         6       <NA>        NA
```

I can describe how to get there in this small toy example in code by accessing the individual data frames but I'm hoping for a solution as elegant as the one suggested by [@Maël](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13460602/ma%C3%ABl) in my previous question which `applies` the solution directly to the list of data frames:

```
# Append the list names hard coded to all column names
# but this should be dynamic within the list not using the data frames
names(df1) <- c("df1 border", "df1 value")
names(df2) <- c("df2 border", "df2 value")

# Add a column which can be used in merge
df1$row_id <- row.names(df1)
df2$row_id <- row.names(df2)

# Merge all dataframes adding rows w/ <NA> where required
# but this should use the list not the individual data frames
df <- merge(df1, df2, all.x=T, all.y=T)
```

Comment: Maybe `merge(df_lst[[1]], df_lst[[2]], by="row.names", all=T, suffixes=paste0("_", names(df_lst)))[,-1]`

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to avoid explicitly referencing the list items as there are hundreds and the number varies. Not sure this could be achieved with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do something like this:
The main task is that cbind needs equal number of rows.
In this example we use `reframe(cur_data()[seq(3),], .by=id) %>%`  after binding to a dataframe. Here it is hardcoded with `3` but we can overcome easily by `max_rows <- max(map_int(df_lst, nrow))`. After this we need a little pivoting tricks:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_lst %>%
  map(~mutate_all(.x, as.character)) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = 'id') %>% 
  reframe(cur_data()[seq(3),], .by=id) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = c(border, value)) %>%
  select(-row)
```

```
  border_df1 border_df2 value_df1 value_df2
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     <chr>    
1 1          A          4         3        
2 2          B          5         5.7      
3 3          NA         6         NA
```

Comment: Thanks, not familiar with tidyverse so I'll have to digest this a little to understand if it can handle varying count of data frames in the list but it looks as if it could...

Comment: Turns out that in the R implementation I have to use (TIBCO Enterperise Runtime for R or TERR) the supported package version is so old that `reframe` does not exist. So I can't really verify it is working but it certainly does so I'll accept the answer w/o having checked. Thanks again, @TarJae!